# Getting a mouse position with JavaFX and Event

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get the position of a mouse click in my JavaFX application. I have an EventHandler as so:

```
EventHandler<Event> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        String eType = event.getEventType().toString();
        if(eType.equals("MOUSE_PRESSED")){
            //mouse position
        }
    }
};
```

which is called on mouse press, release and drag. I'm unable to get the position of the mouse from `Event` and when I try and change `EventHandler<Event>` to `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` I get the message `Type paremeter 'java.awt.event.MouseEvent' is not within it's bounds;  should extend to 'javafx.event.Event'`.

How can I move this over to MouseEvents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the JavaFx [`MouseEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).

Currently you are trying to use the Java.awt [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

Try importing only Java libraries from Javafx and not awt so you can avoid having the wrong type.

Once you fix that, the methods `getX()` and `getY()` should give you the position. (Or depending on what you want that position relative to, `getScreenX()` or `getSceneX()` might be what you want.)

Comment: Ah, of course. To be fair it isn't the first time I've been caught out by the awt vs. javafx differences.

Comment: Indeed, it can very hard to tell whether you are using (or even should use) `javafx`, `awt`, or `swing` classes.